# Python, Pandas: Percentile of grouped data with multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, percentile

I haven't been able to find an answer to this specific question.  I have data that looks like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Product': ['Alpha', 'Alpha', 'Alpha', 'Alpha','Alpha', 'Beta', 'Beta', 'Beta','Beta', 'Gamma', 'Gamma', 'Gamma','Delta','Delta','Epsilon','Epsilon','Epsilon','Epsilon'],'Age': [0,1,2,5,8,0,2,3,5,1,3,2,8,5,1,5,4,2],'Quantity': [114,82,15,35,27,63,32,55,87,50,4,22,6,96,94,3,64,110]})
```

| Product | Age | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alpha | 0 | 114 |
| Alpha | 1 | 82 |
| Alpha | 2 | 15 |
| Alpha | 5 | 35 |
| Alpha | 8 | 27 |
| Beta | 0 | 63 |
| Beta | 2 | 32 |
| Beta | 3 | 55 |
| Beta | 5 | 87 |
| Gamma | 1 | 50 |
| Gamma | 3 | 4 |
| Gamma | 2 | 22 |
| Delta | 8 | 6 |
| Delta | 5 | 96 |
| Epsilon | 1 | 94 |
| Epsilon | 5 | 3 |
| Epsilon | 4 | 64 |
| Epsilon | 2 | 110 |

What I'm looking for is an arbitrary percentile of age, broken down by product, given that there's quantities, *e,g.*:

| Product | 70th Percentile (years) | 90th Percentile (years) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alpha | 0 | 2 |
| Beta | 5 | 5 |
| Gamma | 2 | 2 |
| Delta | 5 | 5 |
| Epsilon | 2 | 4 |

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how `70th` and `90th` percentile columns are calculated?

Comment: @MarceloPaco it essentially says "90% of my inventory is this age or younger."  If you take all the inventory and line it up by age, then go 90% up the line, the age of that one is the 90th percentile. Same with the 70th percentile.

Answer (score 1):

You need a weighted percentile by repeating the quantity for each age. You can create a custom function for that and apply it on each group:

```
import numpy as np

def weighted_percentile(df, p):
    arr = np.percentile(np.repeat(df['Age'], df['Quantity']), p)
    return pd.Series(arr).rename(lambda x: f'{p[x]}th Percentile (years)')

out = (df.groupby('Product', as_index=False, sort=False)
         .apply(weighted_percentile, p=[70, 90]))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   Product  70th Percentile (years)  90th Percentile (years)
0    Alpha                      1.0                      5.0
1     Beta                      5.0                      5.0
2    Gamma                      2.0                      2.0
3    Delta                      5.0                      5.0
4  Epsilon                      2.0                      4.0
```

Comment: Also nice! Though if the amount of groups increases, it gets quite slow, on account of `.apply()` no doubt. But your `rename` + `lambda` made me realize that I can just chain that one, of course!

Comment: `groupby_apply` is not so slow. It depends on the number of groups. Do not confuse with `apply` along index axis. Also, `groupby_apply` can easily run with multiprocessing if needed.

Comment: I did a timeit on both these methods. With OP example: 1.96 ms (using `quantile`) vs. 3.11 ms (using `apply`). With an example containing 30 groups that became: 1.78 ms vs. 14.4 ms. So, that's quite a significant difference, I would say. If performance is really an issue; on this `df`, it doesn't quite matter, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

- Apply [`df.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) using [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) with column "Quantity" as the repeats.
- Group data by column "Product" ([`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)), select column "Age", and apply [`.quantile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.quantile.html) with your percentiles of choice: `[0.7, 0.9]`.
- The rest is to get the desired shape: use [`Series.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) on index `level 1`, and apply `df.reindex` again, this time with unique values from `df['Product']` ([`Series.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html)). This re-establishes the order for the product values.
- Finally, chain [`df.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) to rename your columns, and [`df.rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) to remove the index label.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

perc = [0.7,0.9]
res = (df.reindex(np.repeat(df.index, df['Quantity']))
       .groupby('Product')['Age'].quantile(perc)
       .unstack(1)
       .reindex(df['Product'].unique())
       .rename(lambda x: f"{int(x*100)}th Percentile (years)", axis=1)
       .rename_axis(None, axis=0)
       )

res

         70th Percentile (years)  90th Percentile (years)
Alpha                        1.0                      5.0
Beta                         5.0                      5.0
Gamma                        2.0                      2.0
Delta                        5.0                      5.0
Epsilon                      2.0                      4.0
```

Chain `res.astype(int)`, if you want integers. Incidentally, your desired output contains an error. For "Alpha", you have `70% = 0` and `90% = 2`, but these should be `1` and `5` respectively.